# How to forward a thrown expression from one catch block to another?

Tags: c++, exception

I am writing a program in C++ which handles errors via throwing strings (either `std::string` or `const char*`), like so :

```
if (/* failure condition 1 */)
    throw std::string("Error 1 : ...") + std::to_string(foo);

if (/* failure condition 2 */)
    throw "Error 2 : ...";
```

Then I would catch them this way :

```
try {
    thisIsLikelyToThrowErrors();
} catch (const std::string& e) {
    std::cerr << ":( " << e << std::endl;
} catch (const char* e) {
    std::cerr << ":( " << e << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to avoid writing the same line twice, by forwarding the string from the first `catch` block to the second one :

```
try {
    thisIsLikelyToThrowErrors();
} catch (const std::string& e) {
    throw e.c_str(); // Does not work
} catch (const char* e) {
    std::cerr << ":( " << e << std::endl;
}
```

However this code won't work, the thrown `char const*` simply won't be catched.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the common setup in an independent function externally, calling it from your catches clauses.

In your example, you can do:

```
inline void HandleStringyException(const char* excStr)
{
     //do something
}
```

Then:

```
try {
    thisIsLikelyToThrowErrors();
} catch (const std::string& e) {
    HandleStringyException(e.c_str());
} catch (const char* e) {
    HandleStringyException(e);
}
```

---

**P.S.** It should be mentioned that exceptions are better to be handled polymorphically, and in order to do so, the objects *thrown* should be chosen wisely. As mentioned by others, throwing objects like strings and pointers is a bad practice, and generally you'd like to throw objects derived from std::exception. Sometimes, however, the throwing code is not under your control and you have to make the best of it. I think that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 3):

**No, you cannot do this.**

> `[C++14: 15.1/1]:` When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (15.3); “nearest” means the handler for which the *compound-statement* or *ctor-initializer* following the `try` keyword was most recently entered by the thread of control **and not yet exited**.

You would have to nest entire `try`/`catch` pairs:

```
try {
   try {
       thisIsLikelyToThrowErrors();
   }
   catch (const std::string& e) {
       throw e.c_str(); // Does not work
   }
}
catch (const char* e) {
    std::cerr << ":( " << e << std::endl;
}
```

Ew!

But now you have another problem, in that the `std::string` `e` dies after you've thrown its C-string buffer (it'd stay alive if you re-threw *it*). Probably try to avoid this in general, eh?

*Throw actual exceptions, instead.*

Comment: "The exception
object is destroyed after either the last remaining active handler for the exception exits by any means other
than rethrowing," <-- so the string gets deleted before the outer handler catches the `const char*`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution to your actual problem:

Throw only `std::string` or only `const char*`.

Or even better throw something derived from `std::exception`

Comment: That's not a "yes". That's a "don't even try". A reasonable suggestion (I made it myself) but you didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right. I went the XY path.